# Spacing not correct in html/css

Tags: html, css

The button is aligned to the search input. But I cannot get the spacing fixed.

As you can see in the example the left side has a smaller spacing than the right side compared to the background box. [Project Example](http://www.broadcasteralerts.com/). Also I cannot change the width of the button to solve this, since it's staying that width.

I hope someone can help (Snippet Below)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var regionDropDown = $('.region_dropdown_section'),
      regionButton = regionDropDown.find('button'),
      regionList = regionDropDown.find('.region_dropdown_content').children();

  $(regionList).on('click', function(e){
    var region = e.target;
    regionButton.text(region.text).val(region.text);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url(../images/background/body_background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.SearchSummoners {
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 80px;
}



/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.region_dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.region_dropdown_section {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.region_dropdown_content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.region_dropdown_content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .region_dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.Searchbox_Summoners {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}


#SearchBox {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     width: 80%;
     background-color: white;
     height: 40px;
     float: left;
    }

        .region_dropdown_section {
         position: inherit;
         display: inline-block;
         max-width: 100% !important;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

#SearchInput{
  width: 92%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</div>
  <div class="SearchSummoners">
      <div id="SearchBox">
        <form method="POST">
          <input id="SearchInput" value="Enter the Summoner Name"  onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter the Summoner Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter the Summoner Name'; }"  type="text" name="SummonerName"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="region_dropdown_section">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
        <div class="region_dropdown_content">
          <a href="#">North America</a>
          <a href="#">Europe West</a>
          <a href="#">Europe NE</a>
          <a href="#">Korea</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to alter two CSS values:

First, set the width of the whole div where the button is in to 20% (the search bar is 80%) instead of 95px:

```css
.region_dropdown_section {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Then set the button size to 100% (of the allowed 20%) instead of 80px:

```css
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You sir, you are amazing! Thanks so much!